# SQL query similar to the concept of set (complement or except)

Tags: laravel

I need your help. I just want to display the name of all users (from table users) whose are not in table documents but in today's date

I've tried but I failed
Here is my code

```
public function activeUser(){

    $documents = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('documents', 'users.id', '=', 'documents.user_id')
        ->select('users.fname','users.mname','users.sname','documents.created_at')
        ->where('documents.user_id',null)
        ->where('documents.created_at',null)
        ->get();    

    return view('activity.activity')->with('documents', $documents);
}
```

I don't know to add current date in the where clause.
The above code gave me the all users who are note in table documents but if user exist in documents once will always considered as is in that documents table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "whereBetween" (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses).

```
public function activeUser(){

    $yesterday = Carbon::yesterday();
    $today = Carbon::today();
    $documents = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('documents', 'users.id', '=', 'documents.user_id')
        ->select('users.fname','users.mname','users.sname','documents.created_at')
        ->where('documents.user_id',null)
        ->whereBetween('documents.created_at', [$yesterday, $today])
        ->get();    

    return view('activity.activity')->with('documents', $documents);
}
```

Remember, you can also use "whereNotInBetween" if that better matches your business logic case.